# Scan and put it to Array

Tags: java

I want scan sentence and count how many word is. And than put the sentence to Array. And print it.

It works until System.out.println("단어개수 : " + count);
but it doesn't work after that.

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Midterm_HW00 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    System.out.println("Insert sentence: ");
    
    
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int count =1;
    
    String sentence = scanner.nextLine();   //문자열 읽기    
            
    for(int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++) {   
        if(sentence.charAt(i)==' ') {   //단어 개수를 띄어쓰기 개수로 계산
            count++;
            
        }
    }
    System.out.println("단어 개수: " + count);

    String[] wordArray = new String[30];   //배열 선언
    int word = wordArray.length;
    
    for(int j=0; j<word; j++){
        wordArray[j] = scanner.next();            

       System.out.println("" + wordArray[j]);

    
    
    scanner.close();
   }
}
```

}

Comment: Why do you close your scanner in the for-loop? This means you're closing the scanner every time through the loop. Once you close it, you can't reuse it. Any scanner should only be closed when it will never be used again, perhaps at the end of your program.

Answer (score 0):

you can get all this by using simple method:

```java
String[] array = yourString.split(" ");
int amountOfWords = array.length;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String sentence = scanner.nextLine();

String[] words = sentence.split("[ ]+");
System.out.println("단어 개수: " + words.length);

for(String word : words){
    System.out.println(word);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use string split by a space to generate an array like this `String[] wordArray = sentence.split("\\s+");`

code :

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    System.out.println("Insert sentence: ");
    
    
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int count =1;
    
    String sentence = scanner.nextLine();   //문자열 읽기    
            
    for(int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++) {   
        if(sentence.charAt(i)==' ') {   //단어 개수를 띄어쓰기 개수로 계산
            count++;
            
        }
    }
    System.out.println("단어 개수: " + count);

    String[] wordArray = sentence.split("\\s+");   //배열 선언
    
    
    for(int j=0; j<wordArray.length; j++){       

       System.out.println("" + wordArray[j]);

   }
}
```

Comment: Thx. You save me...ㅜㅜ
I think I need to study abount string split.
Have a good day!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main {
    
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    System.out.println("Insert sentence: ");
            
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int count =1;
    
    String sentence = scanner.nextLine();   
            
    for(int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++) {   
        if(sentence.charAt(i)==' ') {   
            count++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("단어 개수: " + count);
           
    String[] wordArray = new String[] {sentence};
    
    for(int j=0; j<count; j++){
       System.out.println("" + wordArray[j]);
       scanner.close();
   }
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {
   public static void main(String [] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int count = 1;
        String sentence = sc.nextLine();
        // finding the number of word
        for (int i=0; i<sentence.length(); i++) {
            if (sentence.charAt(i) == ' ')
                count += 1;
        }
        System.out.println("The count is : " + count);
        // store the sentence to a string array using split(split by the space)
        String [] sentenceToArray = sentence.split(" ");
        // print all elements inside the array
        for (int i=0; i<sentenceToArray.length; i++)
             System.out.print(sentenceToArray[i]);
   }
}
```